# Is there an interactive visual html editor?

Tags: html, ide, editor

Is there any kind of decent program for html/css that lets you build a website visually? I'm thinking something more along the lines of adobe illustrator or google docs, that lets you put content onto a page and drag things to where you need them to be, but spits out html code when you're done. Something like google web designer but more flushed out and functional, as it's still in beta and has a long way to go. Also, what are these kinds of programs called? (originally thought they where WYSIWYGs )

Comment: Macromedia before they were bought out by Adobe had a product called DreamWeaver, its still around: http://www.adobe.com/CreativeCloud/Dreamweaver‎. I am going to vote to close this as its asking for a Recommendation and that is not covered here as per the [faq]s. In future, for Software Recs ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wordpress, easiest way to achieve what you've said, then you can drag and drop and design the website like you said. WYSIWYG changes textarea to a text editor, [Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) is one of them, not what you want. What you want is called [Content Management System(CMS)](http://searchcontentmanagement.techtarget.com/definition/content-management-system-CMS), wordpress is one of them, you can see a list of CMSs in the article.

Answer (score 0):

A far more economical drag-and-drop HTML builder tool is [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io/).

This is naturally linked to the Bootstrap library and jQuery. But you can just use it to get a flavour of what you want to design. 
Then write your own html/css/js code for the final site.
In fact you can use Bootstrap Studio to build a non-Bootstrap site and make use of its features like designing for different device screen widths.

$29 for a year's use, $60 for perpetual use.

Answer (score 0):

https://html-online.com/editor/ free and easy: copy your html inside, edit, copy back to studio.